# How to list all functions with arguments that a role is allowed to execute in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, functions

I found [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336648/1385429) to list tables a role has permissions on. I found [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034539/1385429) to list all functions with arguments.

My question is: How to list all functions with arguments a role is allowed to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `has_function_privilege` function for that:

```
SELECT p.pronamespace::regnamespace as schema,
       p.proname||'('||pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid)||')' as function
FROM pg_proc p 
WHERE has_function_privilege(p.oid, 'execute');
  and p.pronamespace <> 'pg_catalog'::regnamespace;
```

Comment: Thank you. Now that I know (again) that I can use `has_function_privilege`, I just found another question asking the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769397/list-all-functions-that-can-be-executed-by-a-user

Comment: It works. Just two notes: 1) maybe the condition `p.pronamespace <> 'information_schema'::regnamespace` should be added to remove other general functions, and 2) there is an extra `;` in your code after `has_function_privilege(p.oid, 'execute')` .